# Регулярное выражение-слово после запятой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как регулярным выражением найти слова из 3 букв после запятых. Из трех букв нахожу `\b\w{3}\b`, но никак не придумаю как задать условие чтоб "только те что после запятой".

Answer (score 4):

Позитивный [просмотр назад](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4):

```
(?<=шаблон)
```

Для вашего случая будет что-то вроде:

```
(?<=,)\b\w{3}\b
```

Comment: не работает...

Comment: @221941, на каком тексте проверяете?

Comment: Пробел добавьте:

    (?<=,\s)\b\w{3}\b

Comment: @Deonis, так неинтересно.. Хотя, скорее всего, пробела и нехватало

Comment: Или просто язык не поддерживает эту конструкцию :)